TeX StackExchange search tool question
I see that some questions on the TeX StackExchange don't have any tags. How can i use the integrated search tool to get all existing questions without any tags?
Thanks for your help.

where are untagged posts please give a link , I tried to find some on sede but only could find posts tagged wit r as being the shortest tag field, looking for null produced no results https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1856567/shortest-tags

When posting any question on Stack Exchange, the tag is part of a required field:

So, you can't ask a question without providing a tag. However, in some cases a question may be considered untagged (a contradiction really, as it's tagged with the tag untagged). For example, this may happen if it was migrated from another site (where we don't have similar tags), or tags previously assigned to it may have been removed. Read more about the untagged tag...
So, if you're looking for untagged questions, you're probably looking for those tagged untagged, or you can search using [untagged].

You can use the Data Explorer to search for posts with various constraints, this shows the posts with shortest tag list (all tgged r) I don't see any posts with no tags If I amend the query to look for string length 0 or the field being null, then no results are returned.
https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1856567/shortest-tags
Are you sure you saw untagged posts? I didn't think that was possible.
